# Concatenación de cadenas

Tags: c, string, punteros

Tengo que hacer un programa que pida dos cadenas (a y b), en la cadena "c" tiene que juntar la cadena "a" y "b". El programa corre, el problema es que no me imprime la cadena "c". No puedo usar `strcat` para realizar la concatenación

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void concat(char *cadA[50], char *cadB[50], char *cadC[100]){
int i=0,j=0;
    do{
        cadC[i]= cadA[i];
        i++;}
    while(cadA[i]!='\0');

    do{
        cadC[i]=cadB[j];
        i++;
        j++;}
    while(cadB[j-1]!='\0');
}

int main(){

char *cadA, *cadB, *cadC; 
    printf("Ingresar cadena de máximo 50 caracteres\n");
    scanf("%s", &cadA);
    printf("Ingresar cadena de máximo 50 caracteres\n");
    scanf("%s", &cadB);
    concat(&cadA, &cadB, &cadC);
    printf("%s", &cadC);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Error 1: Punteros no inicializados**

```
char *cadA; 
scanf("%s", &cadA);
```

`cadA` es un puntero que no está inicializado, luego apunta a una dirección aleatoria y, si intentas modificar la memoria apuntada podrán pasar dos cosas:

- Que corrompas memoria de otra aplicación. Esto sucede en sistemas operativos antiguos que no controlan los accesos a memoria.
- Que el sistema operativo mate tu aplicación... de no hacerlo sucedería lo comentado en el primer punto.

Dado que el mensaje indica que la cadena puede tener hasta 50 caracteres, lo que más sentido tiene es declarar un array de tamaño fijo con tamaño 51 (50 caracteres de longitud más el finalizador `\0`).

```
char cadA[51], cadB[51];
```

Y ahora le llega el turno a `cadC`... ¿Qué tamaño le ponemos? Como estás concatenando cadenas (de tamaño máximo 50) y solo va a ser necesario que tenga un finalizador, el tamaño mínimo es 101 (o 102 si quieres usar un separador entre ambas cadenas):

```
char cadC[101];
```

**Error 2: Las lecturas son incorrectas**

```
scanf("%s", &cadA);
```

`scanf` necesita que los argumentos se le faciliten en forma de punteros porque es la única forma que hay en C para modificar variables que no pertenecen a la propia función (aparte de las variables estáticas). Pues bien, `char[]` es, de por sí, **un puntero**, luego no hay que usar aquí el operador de referencia `&`.

Al declarar `char cadA[51]`, en `cadA` se almacena únicamente la dirección en la que comienza el array. El uso de `scanf` con punteros es así:

```
scanf("%s",cadA);
```

Y lo mismo le sucede a `printf`:

```
printf("%s", &cadC);
//           ^ Esto sobra
```

**Cuidado con los punteros dobles**

Ya hemos visto que `cadA` es un puntero, luego añadir un asterisco a la declaración sirve para crear punteros dobles:

```
void concat(char *cadA[50], char *cadB[50], char *cadC[100]){
//               ^               ^               ^
```

El único motivo que justificaría que `concat` reciba un puntero doble es porque, bajo ciertas condiciones, `concat` tiene que modificar la dirección a la que apunta uno de esos punteros... y no es el caso. `concat` solo manipula la información que está apuntada por los punteros, luego lo esperable es que `concat` reciba punteros simples:

```
void concat(char cadA[50], char cadB[50], char cadC[100]){
```

**Consejo 1: Declaración confusa**

En C, al declarar arrays de tamaño fijo, el mismo se ubica en posiciones consecutivas de la memoria. Al encontrarse los elementos en posiciones consecutivas, (y teniendo en cuenta que `cadA` tiene consideración de puntero), el compilador **no necesita** conocer el tamaño de cada array nada más que en la declaración. La excepción la encontrarás con los arrays multidimensionales... pero no es el caso que nos ocupa en esta pregunta.

Lo que quiero decir es que al llamar a `concat` **no es recomendable** que indices el tamaño de cada arreglo:

- No es necesario
- Puede dar lugar a confusiones si los valores indicados ahí no coinciden con los reales.

En su lugar declara la función con punteros:

```
void concat(char* cadA, char* cadB, char* cadC)
```

E incluso puedes mejorar un más la legibilidad del programa marcando `cadA` y `cadB` como constantes ya que su valor no debe ser modificado dentro de la función. Al declarar algo como `const` permites que el compilador te avise si tu código intenta modificar la variable en cuestión (te ayuda a encontrar errores):

```
void concat(char const* cadA, char const* cadB, char* cadC)
```

**Consejo 2: Aritmética de punteros**

El algoritmo de `concat` queda más limpio si se usa aritmética de punteros. De hecho podemos aprovechar que los punteros se pasan por valor para modificar su posición sin miedo:

```
void concat(char const* cadA, char const* cadB, char * cadC)
{
  // Copiamos la primera cadena
  for( ; *cadA != '\0'; ++cadA, ++cadC )
    *cadC = *cadA;

  // Copiamos la segunda cadena
  for( ; *cadB != '\0'; ++cadB, ++cadC )
    *cadC = *cadB;

  *cadC = '\0'; // Finalizamos la cadena
}
```

Comment: No se por que nacie lo menciona, lo comentaré en tu respuesta que parece la más completa. Al leer cadenas lo recomendable es especificar la longitud máxima para que no haya riesgo de sobreescribir datos del programa. En scanf puede realizarse poniendo la cantidad máxima de caracteres visibles entre el % y la s. En este caso: scanf("%50s, cadX);

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz no lo he puesto porque en ese caso también tienes que tener previsto un mecanismo de limpieza del buffer de entrada... y si lo pongo cuando no lo han hecho en la pregunta entonces habría que explicar por qué lo he puesto y cómo funciona y la respuesta final acaba demasiado desvirtuada. Aplico un límite en mis respuestas en cuanto a sugerencias se refiere...

Answer (score 2):

- Que una array de caracteres tenga una longitud de 50 items no significa que vaya a almacenarlos todos, esto debido a que en la ultima posición de una cadena debe almacenar el carácter nulo`\0`.

  - **La solución sería** asignar un carácter adicional al tamaño total de tu array
- A través del uso de los parametros de tu función `concat` intentas enviar las cadenas de texto que has recogido usando el método `scanf` por lo tanto el tipo de dato que intentas enviar debe ser igual al tipo de dato de las variables que quieres enviar, `*[]` no es igual a `[]` o a `*`.

  - **La solución sería** usar punteros `char *MiArgumento` o usar una cadena con tamaño estático `char MiArgumento[20]` como argumento
- Tus variables cad A/B/C, son punteros y debes asignarle memoria antes
  de poder usarlas, o introducirles algún valor usando `scanf()`

  - **La solución sería** definir un array estático `char *MiArray[51]` o definir un puntero y declararle memoria a través de alguna función com `Array = malloc(sizeof(char)*51)`
- El ampersand (este simbolo => &) se usa en scanf debido a que por defecto, cuando se pasa una variable a una función, el valor de esta es copiada, usando el ampersand podemos enviarle la dirección de memoria a una función y modificar su valor, sin embargo cuando se pasa un puntero o un array, no es necesario debido a por defecto la dirección de memoria es pasada, lo que significa que podemos modificar el valor.

Esta es una posible solución para los varios errores de tu programa, adicionalmente le sumo uno al valor total de la cadena C para agregarle y carácter adicional con el fin de separar la primera cadena de la segunda..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void concat(char cadA[50], char cadB[50], char cadC[100]){
int i=0,j=0;
    do{
        cadC[i]= cadA[i];
        i++;}
    while(cadA[i]!='\0');

    cadC[i++] = ' ';

    do{
        cadC[i]=cadB[j];
        i++;
        j++;}
    while(cadB[j-1]!='\0');
}

int main(){

char cadA[51], cadB[51], cadC[102]; 
    printf("Ingresar cadena de máximo 50 caracteres\n");
    scanf("%s", cadA);
    printf("Ingresar cadena de máximo 50 caracteres\n");
    scanf("%s", cadB);
    concat(cadA, cadB, cadC);
    printf("%s", cadC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al menos si es tan estricto ocupar un método, sino podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char cadA[50], cadB[50], i, j;

        printf("Ingresar cadena de máximo 50 caracteres: \n");
        scanf("%s", cadA);

        printf("Ingresar cadena de máximo 50 caracteres: \n");
        scanf("%s", cadB);

        // calcular la longitud de la cadena cadA
        // y almacenarlo en i
        for(i = 0; cadA[i] != '\0'; ++i);

        for(j = 0; cadB[j] != '\0'; ++j, ++i)
        {
            cadA[i] = cadB[j];
        }

        cadA[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s", cadA);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ojala que cadA no mida 45 y cadB 30... porque va a ser muy interesante lo que va a pasar...